# PySpark count common occurrences

Tags: pyspark

After doing a market basket analysis, extracting the rules,... I also want to count the common occurrence of items - as tuples - to visualize them in Tableau. Below you find the items for each ID / members of a basket.

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("ID_1", "Butter"),
("ID_1", "Toast"),
("ID_1","Ham"),
("ID_2", "Ham"),
("ID_2", "Toast"),
("ID_2","Egg"),],
["ID","VAL"])

df.show()

+----+------+
|  ID|   VAL|
+----+------+
|ID_1|Butter|
|ID_1| Toast|
|ID_1|   Ham|
|ID_2|   Ham|
|ID_2| Toast|
|ID_2|   Egg|
+----+------+
```

This is the result I want to achieve:

```
res = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("Butter", "Butter", 0),
("Butter", "Toast", 1),
("Butter", "Ham", 1),
("Butter", "Egg", 0),
("Toast", "Toast", 0),
("Toast", "Ham", 2),
("Toast", "Egg", 1),
("Ham", "Ham", 0),
("Ham", "Egg", 0),
("Egg", "Egg", 0),],
["VAL_1","VAL_2", "COUNT"])

res.show()

+------+------+-----+
| VAL_1| VAL_2|COUNT|
+------+------+-----+
|Butter|Butter|    0|
|Butter| Toast|    1|
|Butter|   Ham|    1|
|Butter|   Egg|    0|
| Toast| Toast|    0|
| Toast|   Ham|    2|
| Toast|   Egg|    1|
|   Ham|   Ham|    0|
|   Ham|   Egg|    0|
|   Egg|   Egg|    0|
+------+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below, you'll might also want to use `withColumnRenamed` to rename the calculated column

```
df.groupBy(['ID','VAL']).count().show()
```